# How do we add action to Tab Bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am using Tab Bar i.e. Bottom bar and have 5 tab bar items, i want to assign a method to each, so that i can navigate to other views on tab bar item click.

I've been looking for some clues, but couldn't make it.

Comment: you can use its delegate method and check which tab is clicked

Comment: @PiyushRathi how to do it ?

Comment: have you taken TabBarController?

Comment: @PiyushRathi No just Tab Bar not Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: Could you explain your problem with any example?

Comment: set Delegate to TabBar and use `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar 
 didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;` method.

Comment: neither UITabbar nor UITabBarItem are inherited from UIControll to track user event, So delegate is the only way to achieve tabbarItem selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UITabBarDelegate`.

Implement your class and inherit the protocol by adding  after your class definition

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
```

and then use method tabBar:didSelectItem: in that class

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    // Do Stuff!
    // if(item.title == @"First") {...}
}
```

May be it will help you

Comment: @Shikha Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift

Implement UITabBarDelegate and use method didSelect

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    }
}
```

Also create IBOutlet to toolbar

`toolbar.delegate = self`